# How can I configure different spacing rules inside for loops in IntelliJ Idea's code style settings?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am currently working on a Java project, and I am finding IntelliJ Idea's code style system to be extreamly frustrating as it refuses to accept the settings that I want to give it. Specifically, I want spaces around various operators *unless they're inside a for loop's header*. For example, the following code should be output:

```
for(int x=0;x<10;++x){ // no spaces around operators when they're in a for loop's header
    System.out.println(x);
}

int a = 10; //spaces around = when not in a for loop's header
int b = 50;
a = b;
if(a < b){ //an if statement is not a for loop's header
    doSomething();
}
```

In essence, I want IntelliJ to make an exception to normal space rules when in the header of a for loop, removing these spaces. It looks absolutely disgusting to me to have what should be a dense construction filled with superfluous spaces, to the point that it is making me not want to use IntelliJ Idea at all, despite its numerous great features. THis, for example, severely diminishes the utility of its automatic refactoring ability because I need to manually go through and fix its formatting errors after every refactor.

When I look in the code style settings, the "around operators" checkboxes seem to have no mechanism for a different setting inside for loops:
[image: screenshot of aforementioned settings in IntelliJ Idea]

How can I get IntelliJ Idea to format my code correctly?

Comment: You want to have inconsistent behavior of formatting around relational operators and I doubt that's possible. What IDE supports this formatting?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I'm not aware of any IDEs that do or do not. It's possible that Eclipse does, since I used it when I learned Java and picked up the habit.

Comment: In that case, you might want to try eclipse formatter plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter . But I seriously doubt this code style is supported by any IDE.

Comment: There is no such setting in IntelliJ IDEA, and there is no public code style standard that accepts such formatting. If you want to work with other developers in the future, it's generally a good idea to get used to a broadly accepted code style, and not to insist on sticking to a style that no one else uses.